# What's the best way to go through > 100 conditions in one SELECT statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that fetches some groups in Moodle:

```sql
select 
    g.id groupid, 
    g.name groupname, 
    count(distinct gm.userid)
from prefix_groups g
    left join prefix_groups_members gm on gm.groupid = g.id
group by g.id
```

output

```
| groupid | groupname | count(distinct gm.userid) |
|---------|-----------|---------------------------|
| 1       | 20NEW-4A  | 6                         |
| 2       | 18PAR-5F  | 3                         |
| 3       | 20BER-6G  | 2                         |
| 4       | 50NEV-6G  | 6                         |
| 5       | 34HOG-5Q  | 77                        |
| 6       | 10BAT-GG  | 5                         |
| etc.    | etc.      | etc.                      |
```

I want to add a column called `location`, which lists the location of the group (as per the groupname standard in this platform. e.g. BER = Berlin). I have over 100 of these locations to filter on. I know I can throw all of them in a `case` statment and call it a very long day (such as below), but I want to do it the most efficient way possible. In this instance, I cannot create a temporary table to do this. Any ideas?

```sql
select 
    g.id groupid, 
    g.name groupname, 
    case when substring(g.name, 3, 3) = 'BER'
        then 'Berlin'
        when substring(g.name, 3, 3) = 'NEW'
        then 'Newcastle'
        -- etc.
    end location,
    count(distinct gm.userid)
from prefix_groups g
    left join prefix_groups_members gm on gm.groupid = g.id
group by g.id
```

output:

```
| groupid | groupname | location  | count(distinct gm.userid) |
|---------|-----------|-----------|---------------------------|
| 1       | 20NEW-4A  | Newcastle | 6                         |
| 2       | 18PAR-5F  | Paris     | 3                         |
| 3       | 20BER-6G  | Berlin    | 2                         |
| 4       | 50NEV-6G  | Neverland | 6                         |
| 5       | 34HOG-5Q  | Hogwarts  | 77                        |
| 6       | 10BAT-GG  | Bath      | 5                         |
| etc.    | etc.      | etc.      | etc.                      |
```

Comment: What is the full content of `g.name`? We only see the substrings

Comment: Save the relation (code-location) into separate table and join it to your query.

Comment: @juergend - `g.name` is groupname as per the first query and it's output.

Comment: @Akina, not sure if you missed this part of my post: `In this instance, I cannot create a temporary table to do this.`. It's not worth going into why here, but I'm basically hamstrung into only using `select` statements to perform this query.

Comment: The answer updated.

Comment: If you want your query to be more readable you could put your location logic into a function (handy if your're using it in more than one place) - so you'd write it in your query like SELECT ... yourFunc(g.name) location - this will of course just shorten your query and not improve performance

Comment: Normalise your schema, so that you're not joining on a substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE locations ( code CHAR(3), location VARCHAR(255) );

INSERT INTO locations VALUES ('BER', 'Berlin'), ('NEW', 'Newcastle'), ... ;
```

and then

```
select 
    g.id groupid, 
    g.name groupname, 
    locations.location,
    count(distinct gm.userid)
from prefix_groups g
left join prefix_groups_members gm on gm.groupid = g.id
LEFT JOIN locations ON substring(g.name, 3, 3) = locations.code
group by g.id, g.name, locations.location;
```

---

For to improve the performance you may add generated column into `prefix_groups` and join by it avoiding a function in joining condition.

---

> In this instance, I cannot create a temporary table

If so then for to avoid long CASE you may use an expression like:

```sql
ELT(FIND_IN SET(SUBSTRING(g.name, 3, 3), 'BER,NEW,...'), 'Berlin', 'Newcastle', ...) AS location
```

I'm not sure that this will be more effective. But it will be shorter with guarantee.

PS. You may use another variant of CASE function:

```
case substring(g.name, 3, 3) when 'BER' then 'Berlin'
                             when 'NEW' then 'Newcastle'
                             -- etc.
                             end location,
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `substring(g.name, 1, 3)`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 See values example in the question - first two digits must be removed.

Comment: I see, my bad. I've tested in fiddle with corresponding data example and its working. +1 on this very interesting way!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Marking this as the answer. I found your last choice (using case and substring) ran the smoothest. Thanks for your help!!